# How to save form input into json data and save into 1 field table

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

I have form input with radio button like this `

```
 <form class="form-group" action="/user" method="post">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody><tr>
      <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan</th>
      <th style="width: 60px">Tidak Baik</th>
      <th style="width: 60px">Baik</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.</td>
      <td><input style="border:none" type="text" name="text1" value="Periksa kondisi kelistrikan dan kabel ,pastikan tidak ada yang terkelupas"></td>

      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input1" value="false" checked></label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input1" value="true"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.</td>
      <td><input style="border:none" type="text" name="text2" value="Periksa kondisi kabel dan tempat sambungan"></td>

          <td>
              <label><input type="radio"  name="input2"  value="false" checked></label>
          </td>
          <td>
              <label><input type="radio"  name="input2" value="true"></label>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.</td>
      <td><input style="border:none" type="text" name="text3" value="Periksa kondisi pencetakan (tinta dan kertas printer)"> </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input3"  value="false"  checked></label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input3" value="true"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.</td>
      <td> <input style="border:none" type="text" name="text4" value="Fix and squish bugs"> </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input4"  value="false" checked></label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <label><input type="radio"  name="input4" value="true"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <input type="hidden" name="alat_id" value="1">        
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

  </tbody>

</table>
      <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="name" value="post">Submit</button>
       </div>
</form>
```

From this input I have the results (accidentally made an error)

Environment & details:

```
GET Data empty
POST Data
question1   
"Periksa kondisi kelistrikan dan kabel ,pastikan tidak ada yang terkelupas"
answer1 
"false"
question2   
"Periksa kondisi kabel dan tempat sambungan"
answer2 
"false"
question3   
"Periksa kondisi pencetakan (tinta dan kertas printer)"
answer3 
"false"
question4   
"Fix and squish bugs"
answer4 
"false"
alat_id 
"1"
_token  
"buno7LyZ9PLaq3ByKpDYlNz0TuaagV8HPbhqznT8"
name    
"post"
```

I want to input this on DB , in the table 'Pemeliharaan', column 'Pertanyaan'.

And I want to add this field tabel like this :

```
{ "question 1":"true", "question 2":"false", 
  "question 3":"true", "question 4":"false",
  "question 5":"true" }
```

I want save like that because i want to make this to json data .

My controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new pemeliharaa;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user->user_id = $id;
    $user->alat_id = $request->alat_id;
    $user->pertanyaan ="";/in here i dont know what i do
    $user->catatan = "empty";
    $user->status = "week";


    $user->save();
    dd($user);

}
```

can someone help me ?

Comment: You will need create a one to many questions table. Alternatively, if the amount of questions are fixed, you could add question1, answer1, q2, a2, ... fields to the existing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use json_encode()

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new pemeliharaa;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user->user_id = $id;
    $user->alat_id = $request->alat_id;
    $user->pertanyaan = json_encode($request->except(['_token']));
    $user->catatan = "empty";
    $user->status = "week";


    $user->save();
    dd($user);

}
```

```php
$request->only(['question', 'answer']);
```

Comment: its work but this format is like this {"question1":"what are you doing","answer1":"false"}   , can i edit this to {"question 1":"true"} . ??

Comment: oh i know , i just need more $request-> expect

Comment: you can use only for particular inputs $request->only(['question', 'answer']);